# MYSQL8 - How to Split Dynamic Length String by a Delimeter?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have this sample strings from my database, my goal is to split the column value to individual columns of 5 and if the value is not present for other columns then it should return 0 as value

```
Row1
ColumnID: 1
Column Value: "1,2,3"

Row2
ID: 2
Column Value: "1,2,3,4,5"
```

My goal output is to have this

```
Row1
ColumnID: 1
Column Level1: 1
Column Level2: 2
Column Level3: 3
Column Level4: 0
Column Level5: 0

Row2
ID: 2
Column Level1: 1
Column Level2: 2
Column Level3: 3
Column Level4: 4
Column Level5: 5
```

But the generated output is this

```
Row1
ColumnID: 1
Column Level1: 1
Column Level2: 2
Column Level3: 3
Column Level4: 3
Column Level5: 3

Row2
ID: 2
Column Level1: 1
Column Level2: 2
Column Level3: 3
Column Level4: 4
Column Level5: 5
```

This is my current query

```
SELECT  
    a.columnval,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 1), ',', -1) as column1, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 2), ',', -1) as column2, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 3), ',', -1) as column3, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 4), ',', -1) as column4, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 5), ',', -1) as column5 
FROM mytable a
```

However If I have a string "1,2,3"
Getting column1, column2,  column3 is not a problem, the problem is if the string I have only has "1,2" when it tries to get column3 the value being returns is 2, wherein it should return 0, because column3 for string "1,2" is not present.

I think I need to determine the length or check length before getting the column values, but i dont know how to do it in MYSQL

Comment: MySQL (or any database, really) probably isn't the best place to be doing this transformation.  Instead, consider doing this from you app layer, e.g. in PHP.

Comment: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,635524,635529 
might help

Comment: The simplest solution is in using `CONCAT(single_path, ',0,0,0,0')` instead of `single_path` in SUBSTRING_INDEX argument :)

Comment: Specify PRECISE MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina im using mysql8, i have modified the question to add the version, thanks

Comment: *im using mysql8* I have asked for PRECISE version, not for approximate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5),
cte2 AS ( SELECT id FROM test ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT test.id, jsontable.*
          FROM test
          CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( CONCAT('["', REPLACE(test.value, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                                 "$[*]" COLUMNS( num FOR ORDINALITY,
                                                 value VARCHAR(254) PATH "$" )
                               ) AS jsontable )
SELECT cte2.id ColumnID, 
       cte1.num ColumnLevel, 
       COALESCE(cte3.value, 0) value
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
LEFT JOIN cte3 ON cte1.num = cte3.num
              AND cte2.id = cte3.id
ORDER BY cte2.id, cte1.num
```

or

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5),
cte2 AS ( SELECT id, num 
          FROM test
          CROSS JOIN cte1 ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT test.id, jsontable.*
          FROM test
          CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( CONCAT('["', REPLACE(test.value, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                                 "$[*]" COLUMNS( num FOR ORDINALITY,
                                                 value VARCHAR(254) PATH "$" )
                               ) AS jsontable )
SELECT cte2.id ColumnID, 
       cte2.num ColumnLevel, 
       COALESCE(cte3.value, 0) value
FROM cte2
LEFT JOIN cte3 USING (id, num)
ORDER BY cte2.id, cte2.num
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=347bccdb12933a2270e96b1c4343fd54)

Needed MySQL version 8.0.4 or newer.

Comment: this works nicely, although i dont understand whats happening, Thank You,

Comment: @apelidoko Execute `WITH cte3 AS (...) SELECT * FROM cte3` (or even its SELECT only) and investigate the output consulting with JSON_TABLE description in User Manual. This is the only point which may by problematic for to understand, all another steps are simple.

Answer (score 1):

Following query should work:

```
SELECT  
    a.id,
    case 
       when tmplen < 1
       then 0
       else
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 1), ',', -1)
    end as column1,
    case 
       when tmplen < 2
       then 0
       else
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 2), ',', -1)
    end as column2,
    case 
       when tmplen < 3
       then 0
       else
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 3), ',', -1)
    end as column3,
    case 
       when tmplen < 4
       then 0
       else
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 4), ',', -1)
    end as column4,
    case 
       when tmplen < 5
       then 0
       else
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(single_path, ',', 5), ',', -1)
    end as column5
FROM mytable a 
inner join
   (select id, 
           LENGTH(single_path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(single_path, ',', '')) + 1 as tmpLen
    from mytable
   ) t
on t.id = a.id
```

Please find the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee02868b792583a0eac55c84901411fe).

Here, with `LENGTH(single_path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(single_path, ',', '')) + 1`, I am calculating no of items in each `single_path` records & joining it with original table based on `id`.

While fetching results, I am using that `tmpLen (no of items for each record)` to decide whether to display `substring` or `0` as output.

Comment: this is also nice and good answer, it had the same output i wanted, 
i know that the condition is hard coded but it does the work,  the number of columns i need will never exceed 5 even in the future so i think it should work, thanks alot

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but if condition never exceeds 5, then this answer should work better as far as performance goes. You can check the performance (if you care about that) & accept answer accordingly.